# step in proof Spivak about partition of unity

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

I have a question over theorem 3-11 in Spivak (see below)
[image]

They mention 'some open set $U$' containing $A$. I have a simple question: is it correct that we could take
$$
U=\bigcup_i D_i^o,
$$
where $D_i^o$ is the interior of $D_i$. I am hesitating because they use the letter $U$ instead of $D$, but using the interiors of $D_i$ is what makes most sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right: you can take$$U=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathring{D_i}.$$That's almost certainly what Spivak had in mind. And please note that Michael Spivak is a human being, not a committee; I wrote this because you wrote “they” in your question. He he wrote several books and therefore perhaps that you could have told us which one it is (perhaps *Calculus on manifolds*).

Comment: It does say it's *Calculus on Manifolds* in the top of the second rendered page, indeed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I missed that.